# Vue to PHP array - fopen and regx

Tags: php, laravel

I have a vue files (many of) similar to the example below.
I want to be able to use part of it within PHP to make some tests with.

In short I would like to have something like this

$formFields = array('key=>'value' .....) which has been created from the 'fields' object near the bottom, within the data -> fields -> fields area.

I tried a fair bit, but failed

The general logic I had was

```
$code = file_get_contents('/resources/js/Components/NameOfVueFile.vue');
$fields = 'some sort of regx, which I could not do- got close with (?s)(?<=fields:)(.*?)(?=],)';
$array = 'no idea how to do that part';
```

```
    <template>
    <AsideLayout v-bind="$props" :loading="state.is(AsideState.LOADING)">
        <template v-slot:title>{{ data.id ? 'Edit Account Type' : 'Account Type Form'}}</template>
        <SensesForm
            v-model="accountType"
            v-model:fields="fields"
            v-model:error="error"
            url="/api/v2/account-types"
            :id="data.id"
            @stateChange="state = $event"
            @success='formSuccess'
            :aside-index="asideIndex"
        ></SensesForm>
    </AsideLayout>
</template>

<script>
import AsideLayout from '../../Layout/AsideLayout.vue';
import SensesForm from '../Common/SensesForm.vue';
import Aside from '../../../Mixins/Aside';
import eventHub from '../../../Support/EventHub';
import AsideState from "../../../States/AsideState";

export default {
    components: {
        SensesForm,
        AsideLayout,
    },

    mixins: [Aside],

    data() {
        return {
            state: new AsideState(),
            AsideState,
            accountType: {
                title: null,
                code: null,
                include_in_totals: false,
                payment_reference: null,
            },
            error: null,
            fields: [
                {
                    title: 'Account Type Information',
                    description: 'Basic information about the account type',
                    fields: [
                        {key: 'title', type: 'text'},
                        {key: 'code', type: 'text'},
                        {key: 'include_in_totals', type: 'toggle'},
                        {key: 'payment_reference', type: 'text'},
                    ],
                },
            ],
        };
    },

    methods: {
        formSuccess(data) {
            eventHub.emit('account-type-updated', data);
            this.$asides.pop();
        },
    },
};
</script>
```